# The constructor is undefined in a simple exercice

Tags: java

I just started learning java without any prior knowledge about programming. I run into an error whe I do a simple exercice.

```
public class Book{

    String title;

    String author;

    int numberOfPages;

    String publisher;


public Book (String titleBook, String authorBook, int pagesBook, String publisherBook){

    title = titleBook;
    author = authorBook;
    numberOfPages = pagesBook;
    publisher = publisherBook;

}  
public static void main (String[] args){

    
    Book myBook = new Book ("Seeker","Jack McDevitt",368);
    System.out.println(myBook);
}
}
```

It says my constructor is undefined so I looked a bit and I can't quite get what mistake(s) I'm making.

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: There is no constructor with 3 parameters, the defined one is with 4 parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the paramters that your constructor expecting and what you're passing throw. You had build a constructor with 4 arguments and you're providing only 3 in his creation. You must give it 4 our build a new constructor with 3 paramters, without the publisher in that case.

The correct will be:

```
Book myBook = new Book ("Seeker","Jack McDevitt",368, "publisher");
```

E.g:

```
Book myBook = new Book ("Seeker","Jack McDevitt",368, "Polaris");
```

Will work as well if you create a new constructor, like:

```
public Book (String titleBook, String authorBook, int pagesBook)
    title = titleBook;
    author = authorBook;
    numberOfPages = pagesBook;
    publisher = null; //In that case, you need to set null here

}
```

Comment: Okay it was as simple as that, thanks a lot !

Comment: Thats great, be welcome to java! Please, make sure to mark the answer as correct!!

Comment: Also quick question while I'm on it, when I run the program, instead of printing myBook with all of the variables I put into it, it prints ```Book@1eb44e46```

Comment: I'll do it as soon as I can, I still have to wait 6 minutes to do it